# Сумма матриц (Python)

Tags: python, массивы

Нужна помощь по решению задачи:
Заданы две целочисленные матрицы, каждая из которых состоит из N строк и M столбцов. Требуется вычислить их сумму.

Не могу решить вопрос, как считать данные, когда они разделены между собой. Входящие данные следующие:

```
3 4
4 -2 6 1
-1 7 -4 3
5 3 9 4

2 -3 2 7
5 1 -1 0
-2 3 -4 2
```

Как корректно считать данные, чтобы на выходе получилось 2 списка вида:

```
[[4, -2, 6, 1], [-1, 7, -4, 3], [5, 3, 9, 4]] и [[2, -3, 2, 7], [5, 1, -1, 0], [-2, 3, -4, 2]]
```

Comment: посмотрите ответ там https://pythonworld.ru/numpy/2.html   или требуется всё вручную посчитать ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ss9ozw – вот этот перенос строки мешает корректно считать поступающие данные.

Answer (score 0):

Читаем `n` раз строку и делим ее на числа.

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
arr1 = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
input() # считываем \n, чтобы не мешал
arr2 = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]

s = [[arr1[i][j] + arr2[i][j] for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Спасибо, но получается следующее https://prnt.sc/ss9qfe, то есть пустой список добавляется. То есть вот эти данные http://prntscr.com/ss9rlj не попадают.

Comment: @Toshich_42, ну чтобы взять в учет этот перенос строки, просто считайте его после первого массива, input()

Comment: спасибо! Простая вещь, но не додумался сразу)